# Is there a problem with Product Images in the frontend of OroCommerce?

Tags: orocommerce

This is a followup from https://forum.oroinc.com/orocommerce/topic/my-product-images-are-not-displayed-in-the-frontend/

I just merged tag 3.1.20 into my local environment before upgrading on the production server and found the same issue I was facing some time ago.

The only work-around I found was to comment out these lines:

```
if (!$this->configManager->get('oro_frontend.guest_access_enabled')) {
   return false;
}
```

159 - 161 in vendor/oro/customer-portal/src/Oro/Bundle/FrontendAttachmentBundle/Provider/FileUrlProvider.php

I started seeing this problem when I upgraded from 3.1.15 to 3.1.17

Testing in the VM I see that the images show fine (with the commented lines) everywhere but in the list products by category view (URLs like http://localhost:8000/product/?categoryId=7&includeSubcategories=1 or http://localhost:8000/navigation-root/products/by-category/industrial/lighting-products?frontend-product-search-grid%5Brow-view%5D=list-view)

Is anyone having this issue? Thanks!

Comment: I just did a little more digging into the code and found that FileUrlProvider::getFilteredImageUrl is returning the right url (without /admin prefix) given the commented lines, so the problem must be with the usage of such result...

Comment: Another strange thing I found: when I use the command ```composer show oro/platform``` I see the installed version is 3.1.20. If I go to https://github.com/oroinc/platform/blob/3.1.20/src/Oro/Bundle/AttachmentBundle/Provider/FileUrlProvider.php I see that the method getFilteredImageUrl is no longer calling isPublicOrFrontend as I see if I edit the file straight from my vendor directory... what am I missing?

Comment: Apparently the problem is I was looking in the wrong file :(. The file in GitHub is OroAttachmentBundle, while the one in my vendor directory is OroFrontendAttachmentBundle...

Comment: This is the correct file: https://github.com/oroinc/customer-portal/blob/master/src/Oro/Bundle/FrontendAttachmentBundle/Provider/FileUrlProvider.php

Comment: Looks like it's the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61866493/1735724