# images not accessible when removing guest access

Tags: orocommerce

In orocommerce when we remove "Enable Guest Access" tick in "Website Access" to make the store only accessible to logged in customers, all product image urls change and an "admin/" is added to all image urls and then none of the images are accessible any more in frontend.

What should we do to fix this? Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hi. What version of OroCommerce do you use? I can't reproduce it in 4.1.3.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment. We are using version 3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue of the OroCommerce 3.1 community edition. The issue is already fixed in 4.1.

As 3.1 CE is not supported anymore - you have to upgrade.